# Fists of Thunder Quickening Rune

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Now with the hotfix, is fists of thunder still better to use for bosses and more single enemies over the AoE of crippling wave and the rising tide rune?

I personally like to use crippling wave more than be caught off guard without it and get caught up in a large crowd however I always used fists of thunder for the boss fights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, from my experience cripping wave is more efficient (it also works great with multiple enemies and treasure goblins).

Comment: Yeah, I've actually resigned to doing Crippling Wave with the damage reduction rune now that I'm in Inferno!